# SLURM job error: output file won't update

Tags: bash, prolog, jobs, swi-prolog, slurm

After launching a job in SLURM (sbatch job_to_launch) and waiting for it to finish, the output.txt file won't update.

Here is the code:

File: folder1/go/job_to_launch

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N1 -n2 
#SBATCH -A xxx
#SBATCH --time=05:00
#SBATCH --partition=xxx
#SBATCH --error $xxx      
#SBATCH --output $xxx

cd $WORK/folder1

echo "(some SWI-PROLOG_REQUESTS)"| $WORK/bin/swipl file.pl >$WORK/folder1/output/output.txt
```

Tree:

```
 - FOLDER: folder1
    - file.pl
    - FOLDER: output
       - output.txt 
    - FOLDER: go
       - job_to_launch
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Prolog issue? Do each of the commands work in the interpreter?

Comment: No, I don't think it is a Prolog issue because the commands are running fine directly on the interpreter.

Comment: I assume that $WORK points to a network filesystem, not a node-local one? The first thing to do is to look for errors in the fil specified by `--error=`.

Comment: This shoul work in principle. Perhaps show an example with a minimal request and without output redirection? Works for me with `echo "test(3)." | swipl x.pl > out` and x.pl containing `test(X) :- print(X).`.